# Angular - Converting Datepicker to JS Date and sending to API - Timezone horrors

Tags: angular, typescript, date, timezone, dst

`Angular` is pretty new for our organization, with the extent of our `JavaScript` being `jQuery` on Web Forms or `ASP MVC` pages.

Our database and backend code doesn't have a concept of timezones or DST as we are really only concerned about the month, date, and year.

With all that said, I've been running into an unending stream of errors relating to the dates being incorrect when it comes to DST and timezones with different `Angular approaches`.  Typically, the date is off by one when either the backend or Angular does its conversions.

At first, I thought I had a solution with `.toLocaleDateString('en-us')`, but that was breaking on Safari for us.  Then, I thought we had it with `formatDate(myDateVar, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-us', 'UTC)` but that was broken for Europeans (date off by one), but dropping the `'UTC'` fixed that.

So that's the last few attempts I can remember, but this pain has been going on for months as we learn `Typescript` and `Angular`.  Currently, my latest attempt is `formatDate(myDateVar, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-us')` which seems to be working.

Is there a better way or a more standard way to accomplish this without all DST/timezone issues?
All I want is the date they entered into the input and nothing else.  It also seems like we can't just create a date as UTC using the plain `JS Date object`.  Sometimes our inputs are text, other times they are of type date.

Comment: In my opinion, you should only be doing conversions in the backend, if required. The user can change the TZ settings of the machine and you can end up with some pretty bizarre results. When you need the current Date/Time in UTC, you can generally trust the server's TZ info to be current, not so with the client. If the date being sent across is future or past then you should not use time, unless you need it and let the the user explicitly enter it with no conversions.

Comment: Luxon DateTime has really helped out my organization with this issue: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html